# listing Outlook emails by specific date in Python

Tags: python, loops, email, date, outlook

I'm using Python 3.
I'm trying to extract (list / print show) outlook emails by date.

I was trying a loop.. maybe WHILE or IF statement.

Can it be done since ones a string and the other is a date.
Please concide what I've got so far:    Thanks.

```
 1. import win32com.client, datetime
 2. 
 3. # Connect with MS Outlook - must be open.
 4. outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
 5. # connect to Sent Items
 6. sent = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(5).Items  # "5" refers to the sent item of a folder
 7. 
 8. # Get yesterdays date
 9. y = (datetime.date.today () - datetime.timedelta (days=1))
 10. # Get emails by selected date        
 11. if sent == y: 
 12.     msg = sent.GetLast()
 13.     # get Subject line
 14.     sjl = msg.subject
 14.     # print it out                      
 15.     print (sjl)
```

Answer (score 4):

Ive completed the code. Thanks for help.

```
`import sys, win32com.client, datetime
# Connect with MS Outlook - must be open.
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace
("MAPI")
# connect to Sent Items
s = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(5).Items   # "5" refers to the sent item of a 
folder
#s.Sort("s", true)
# Get yesterdays date for the purpose of getting emails from this date
d = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta (days=1)).strftime("%d-%m-%
y")
# get the email/s
msg = s.GetLast()
# Loop through emails
while msg:
    # Get email date 
    date = msg.SentOn.strftime("%d-%m-%y")
    # Get Subject Line of email
    sjl = msg.Subject
    # Set the critera for whats wanted                       
    if d == date and msg.Subject.startswith("xx") or msg.Subject.startswith
    ("yy"):
    print("Subject:     " + sjl + "     Date : ", date) 
    msg = s.GetPrevious() `
```

This works. However if no message according to the constraint if found, it doesnt exit.   Ive tried break which just finds one message and not all, Im wondering if and how to do an exception? or if i try a else d != date it doenst work either (it will not find anything).
I cant see that a For loop will work using a date with a msg(string).
I not sure -- biginner here :)
??

Answer (score 3):

The outlook API has a method, [`Items.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662.aspx), for searching the contents of `.Items`.  If this is the extent of what you want to do, that's probably how you should do it.

---

Right now it seems like your if statement is checking whether *set of emails* is equal to *yesterday*.

Microsoft's documentation says `.Items` is returning a collection of emails which you first must iterate through using a few different methods including `Items.GetNext` or by referencing a specific index with `Items.Item`.

You can then take the current email and access the [`.SentOn` property.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864408.aspx)

```
currentMessage = sent.GetFirst()
while currentMessage:
    if currentMessage.SentOn == y:
        sjl = currentMessage.Subject
        print(sjl)
    currentMessage = sent.GetNext()
```

This should iterate through all messages in the sent folder until `sent.GetNext()` has no more messages to return.  You will have to make sure `y` is the same formatting as what `.SentOn` returns.

If you don't want to iterate through every message, you could probably also nest two loops that goes back in messages until it gets to yesterday, iterates until it is no longer within "yesterday", and then breaks.

Comment: I saw somewhere there is a Restrict method too. I cant find it agian.  It went like if mail items.restrict(to specified date in this case y)  but the examples i saw where not what i first saw.   (im new to python and havent coded for 6yrs. its just a person project :)

Answer (score 1):

The COM API documentation is fairly thorough, you can see the class list for example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863329.aspx). It also documents the various methods you can use to manipulate the objects it has. In your particular example what you are after is to restrict your set of items via date. You will see that there is already a function for that in the items class [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597.aspx). Conveniently it is called Restrict. The only gotcha I can see with that function is that you need to specify the filter that you would like on your items in string form, thus requiring you to construct the string yourself.

So for example to continue your code and restrict by time:

```
#first create the string filter, here you would like to filter on sent time
#assuming you wanted emails after 5 pm as an example and your date d from the code above
sFilter = "[SentOn] > '{0} 5:00 PM'".format(d)
#then simply retrieve your restricted items
filteredEmails = s.Restrict(sFilter)
```

You can of course restrict by all sorts of criteria, just check the documentation on the function. This way if you restrict and it returns an empty set of items you can handle that case in the code rather than having to work with exceptions. So for example:

```
#you have restricted your selection now want to check if you have anything
if filteredEmails.Count == 0:
    #handle this situation however you would like
```